# How to change IP without using proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy

For examle i want to send some data from a form on a page to a website with faked IP but without using proxy servers how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By disconnecting your modem for a long period of time, you are likely to get a new address assigned to you when you turn it back on.

You could also use a VPS (Virtual Private Server).

Or you could use programs which gives you a new IP. (really slow)